# How to manually trigger the afterSetExtremes event from a series click event in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to manually trigger the afterSetExtremes event every time the users  clicks on a serie.

My desire is to be able to access the chart props on the afterSetExtreme event, however the this object is different depending from where the event is invoked.

boilerplate jsfiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/d450e1az/5/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {   chart: {
        type: 'area',
        borderColor: '#000000',
        zoomType: 'x',
        animation: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        events: {
           afterSetExtremes:    function(event) {
           console.log(this);
          }
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            events: {
                click: function (event) {
                    alert(this.index);
                   console.log(this); this.chart.xAxis[0].hcEvents.afterSetExtremes[0](event)
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {data: [21.9, 70.5, 109.4, 121.2, 124.0, 166.0, 115.6, 128.5, 210.4, 190.1, 92.6, 52.4]}] });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using `Highcharts.fireEvent()` method when a point is clicked. Check demo and code posted below.

However, `afterSetExtremes` event was designed to be invoked after extremes are changed. In this case, extremes are fixed, so perhaps you should use a different approach to achieve what you expect.

**Code:**

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      cursor: 'pointer',
      events: {
        click: function(event) {
          Highcharts.fireEvent(this.xAxis, 'afterSetExtremes');
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/raLcquyp/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.fireEvent

Comment: Flawless solution, Thanks!